# Addressing an IOT device not on my home network?

Tags: networking, python, embedded

I have an IOT Wifi device (ESP8266) that I have communicating with my home desktop computer while they are on the same network. Its pretty straightforward, I use python on both ends to open up a socket. The desktop is the client, and it addresses the ESP8266 acting as the server at the local address 192.168.0.118

My question is, how can I do this when the ESP8266 is not on my home network? Say its on my friend's wifi, or even connected to my phone's mobile hotspot. How would I send data between my home computer and the ESP in that situation?

Comment: Are you going to be constantly moving the device across different networks?

Comment: No sir, just on one network. Sorry for the delay, I didnt get a notification

Comment: You'll need to either set up a VPN, or, less securely, port forward on the firewall (if you have a router that's capable).  If this is a home network with no static IP, you'll need to set up Dynamic DNS for any of these options (check out duckdns.org).